# Validate binary search tree using dfs

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

in the following leetcode problem I am having trouble using dfs to validate if a tree is a valid bst

Given the root of a binary tree, determine if it is a valid binary search tree (BST).

A valid BST is defined as follows:

The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys less than the node's key.
The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys greater than the node's key.
Both the left and right subtrees must also be binary search trees.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def isValidBST(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        if root is None:
            return True
        
        if root.left:
            if root.val <= root.left.val:
                return False
            
        if root.right:
            if root.val >= root.right.val:
                return False
            
        return self.isValidBST(root.left) and self.isValidBST(root.right)
```

my thought process is that if we make it to the end without returning false, then we return true.

For example, if we have the following bst

```
                  5
                 / \
                1   4
                   / \
                  3   6
```

starting our dfs I just want to go down to the left and down to the right each time checking our root nodes to be `left < root < right`.

From what I see my dfs works as described below...

```
5 --> 1 and 4
1 --> None and None
None --> True

Now we begin to pop off the stack

5 --> 1 and 4
1 --> True and True

5 --> True and 4
4 --> 3 and 6
3 --> None and None
None --> True

Now pop off the stack

5 --> True and 4
4 --> 3 and 6
3 --> True and True

5 --> True and 4
4 --> True and 6
6 --> None and None
None --> True

pop off the stack

5 --> True and 4
4 --> True and 6
6 --> True and True

5 --> True and 4
4 --> True and True

5 --> True and True (which is True)

stack is empty
returns True
```

So actually my code return `False` which is the correct output because `1 < 5 > 4` and that can't be but when I walked through my code as I explained I get the wrong answer.

Plus on leetcode I get `true` when I should get `false` for the following input...

```
[5,4,6,null,null,3,7]
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and how I should be thinking about this problem. If someone can help me walkthrough my code kinda how I was doing and show me how I am not  returning `True` for the tree I displayed.

Comment: Your function should also take minimum and maximum values as parameter (may be None). If e. g. examining the right subtree of a root with value 5, minimum must be set to 5 in the recursively called function and it must check that all values of the subtree are larger than that.

Comment: Why would I have to check all values be less than my root value for the left subtree. If I check that my root value has both left and right where left < root < right going to the left needs to check if the root of the left subtree also satisfies the same condition but the root of the left subtree is a different value from five and because we do this check for each root by definition isn’t that already checking if the root 5 with all other values implicitly. What I mean is, is 4 less than 5 yes now check if 3 less than 4 yes by definition 3 is less than 5 because 4 less than 5 and so on…

Comment: You already answer yourself - try to draw the `tree` by using last input - failed one.  [5,4,6,null,null,3,7]

Comment: If root is 5 and right subtree root is 6 and its left "subsubtree" root is 3 this would fulfill the checks in your code but violates the "The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys greater than the node's key" requirement because 3 < 5

Comment: Oh yes I see. Thanks. So for the way that I walked through my solution and once my stack was empty I said I returned true which actually my code returns false. Where am I going wrong with my logic. My code works fine for that example tree but when I walkthrough it one by one I thought it would return true which is obviously the wrong answer I know that but just trying to see the actual representation as to what is going on.

Comment: For the first example tree your code doesn't even need a recursive call. At "if root.right:" it already checks that "root.val >= root.right.val" is true ("5 >= 4") and returns False.

Comment: Actually, I'm being very dumb about this and I think I was just having a lack of sleep. I see that it should just terminate early.

Comment: So your question has been answered?

Comment: Yes, so I realized what I was doing wrong, everything is all cleared up now